# Cannot compile CUDA code in VS 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cuda

I recently installed the [Cuda 8.0 toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) in my windows 10 desktop (after removing all v7.5 components). Despite previous versions being incompatible with Visual Studio 2015 I was happy to see that [Nsight](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition) could actually create a CUDA project and samples came with VS 2015 versions of the *.sln* files.

The problem is that when compiling the samples I get errors like this one:

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 8.0.targets(168,9): **error MSB4062**: The "Nvda.Build.CudaTasks.SanitizePaths" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\BuildCustomizations\Nvda.Build.CudaTasks.v8.0.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v3.5, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

The other strange thing is that earlier today I was able to compile the CUDA samples in my laptop that differs only in that it has VS2015 Community Edition installed. **Any suggestions?**

### PS

The deviceQuery sample that contains the cuda headers :

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <helper_cuda.h>
```

in its single *cpp* file (but no actual *.cu* files) is the only one that compiles and runs fine (I do have a CUDA compatible graphics card if that's what you're wondering, as matter of fact all the pre-install actions described in the installation guide were followed).

### System Details

- Windows 10 Pro
- Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.44
- MS Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 / Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
- Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 / Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3 / Microsoft .NET Framework / Version 4.6.01586
- NVIDIA CUDA 8.0 Wizards   8.0
- Wizards to create new NVIDIA CUDA projects and source files.
- NVIDIA Nsight Visual Studio Edition   5.2.0.16223

... even a report from someone succeeding / failing with the same setup would be helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Nvda.Build.CudaTasks.v8.0.dll` assembly dependent on *MS .NET Framework 3.5*, on it's `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v3.5.dll` and `Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll` assembles.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v3.5, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Error means you don't have *MS .NET Framework 3.5* installed or installation is corrupted.

To check is it installed or not type *"Turn Windows features on or off"* in Start menu or go to `Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off`. If *.NET Framework 3.5* is not checked, install it.

Otherwise you should verify and repair installation. Use [.NET Framework Setup Verification tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2008/10/13/net-framework-setup-verification-tool-users-guide/). It verifies the installation state of one or more versions of the *MS .NET Framework*. If errors found use [.NET Framework Cleanup Tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2008/08/28/net-framework-cleanup-tool-users-guide/) to remove *MS .NET Framework 3.5* and install it again.