# Using CUDA with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, parallel-processing, cuda, gpu

I'm trying to install CUDA, but I get a message saying "No supported version of visual studio was found". I think that this is because I am using Visual Studio 2017 (Community), and CUDA currently only supports up to Visual Studio 2015. Unfortunately, Microsoft will not allow me to download old versions of Visual Studio without paying a subscription fee.

Is there a way I can get around the compatibility issue with VS 2017, or can I not use CUDA?

Comment: You can download older versions of visual studio [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/).  Yes, you have to join the dev essentials program, but it is free.

Comment: I just downloaded the VS2015 Update 2 installer now.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

1. If you want to install `CUDA 8.0` with `Visual Studio 2017` you need to install additional components for Visual Studio 2017.
   Click on the Start Menu and type Visual Studio Installer. Open Visual Studio Installer
   Open `Individual components` tab and select `VC++ 2015.3 v140 toolset` 

   under `Compilers, build tools and runtimes`.

[image: install additional components for Visual Studio 2017]

2. You also need to install `.NET Framework 3.5` if you didn't have it installed.
    *`Nvda.Build.CudaTasks.v8.0.dll` assembly [dependents on MS .NET Framework 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39862254/266068)*.

Open Classical Control Panel, go to `Programs and features` 
and press `Turn Windows features on or off`. Check .NET Framework 3.5 and press OK.

[image]

3. Download full `CUDA toolkit` distribution and extract it somewhere on your disk.
4. If you didn't have `CUDA toolkit` installed, do it now. If you have only `Visual Studio 2017` installed, unselect `Visual Studio integration` checkbox.

Now you want to receive the ***`"No supported version of the visual studio was found"`*** error.

But in order to successfully build Cuda toolkit projects in `Visual Studio 2017`, you also need to follow steps 5 and 6.

5. Go to the `CUDAVisualStudioIntegration\extras\visual_studio_integration\MSBuildExtensions` 
   folder in your extracted distribution, copy all the files and paste them to
    `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v140\BuildCustomizations:`

[image: msbuild]

6. In the last step, you will need to edit your `Cuda` projects to recognize NVidia's build tasks from `Visual Studio 2017`. Open your `.vcxproj` file in a text editor and find all occurrences of `CUDA 8.0.props`. Replace the macro at the beginning of the string with `$(VCTargetsPath14)` so that XML snippet would look as follows:

> `<ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
>       <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath14)\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 8.0.props" /></ImportGroup>`

Don't forget to edit the custom targets path at the end of the file:

> `<ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
>       <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath14)\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 8.0.targets" /></ImportGroup>`

**Make sure to double check your path conifuration!**
 
If you use `nvcc` from command prompt you might not be calling `cl.exe` from `Visual Studio` folder!
[image: another cl.exe might be in path]

Now you can build your Cuda project from Visual Studio 2017.

Parts of this solution are from [Oleg Tarasov blog](https://www.olegtarasov.me/how-to-build-cuda-toolkit-projects-in-visual-studio-2017/).

Comment: Do you really need the .net framework? I haven't installed CUDA under VS 2017 yet but don't remember having it installed for older versions.

Comment: @tera ,Personally I hate it. It makes everything slower. But I think you need it. Nvda.Build.CudaTasks.v8.0.dll assembly dependent on MS .NET Framework 3.5

Comment: If you are performing a **custom installation**, do *not* deselect the `Visual Studio Integration` checkbox. It won't work, but if you don't select it, the files in the `MSBuildExtensions` folder mentioned above won't be downloaded.

Comment: @NauticalMile This is only the case if you are using the network installer, which downloads the required files from the installer. If you download the full 1-2GB offline installer, the installer.exe can be extracted (with 7zip or other) and the `MSBuildExtensions` folder is in there.

Comment: Desassembling the DLL, I found that Nvda.Build.CudaTasks.v8.0.dll depends on .NET 4.0, which is commonly installed with VS2017 when we want the .NET profile.

Answer (score 5):

At the moment, Microsoft still seems to be making VS2015 Update 2 community edition available.  You have to join the "dev essentials" program, but it seems to be free.

I was able to download the installer from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/) recently.

Update: CUDA 9 RC was made available yesterday at developer.nvidia.com to registered developers, and it has support for VS 2017.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you everyone for your help. I just wanted to supplement this post with the last pieces of the puzzle. CUDA v9.0 RC is looking for VS2017 to identify as 1910 but the latest update actually identifies as 1911. To fix open .../CUDA/v9.0/include/crt/host_config.h and change this line:
`#if _MSC_VER < 1600 || _MSC_VER > 1910`
to this:
`#if _MSC_VER < 1600 || _MSC_VER > 1911`

You may also have to add the following to your CMakeLists:
`list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS --cl-version=2017)`

Comment: As VS2017 updates we need to increase the _MSC_VER threshold.  I just removed the second condition.

Answer (score 4):

For people seeing this latter.

First, try to just install CUDA 10 (CUDA Toolkit 10.0).

If it still doesn't work without any mods make sure that you have as many VC++ toolsets as you see on the list. Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JH2oX-z38TE), stop at 8:41 and compare the lists.

If for some reason you have to use CUDA 9.0 - 9.2 you will need to jump some hoops:

- For cmd builds set vcvars_ver=14.11 - [see this answer](/questions/43745099#answer-49616764)
- For IDE builds set Platform Toolset (in project properties - General) to

  - Visual Studio 2017 (v141)) or
  - Visual Studio 2015 (v140))

If you have very customized cmd based build, hunt `#if _MSC_VER` (in `.../CUDA/.../include/crt/host_config.h`) and remove trailing `|| _MSC_VER > ...`

Answer (score 2):

In order to get working Cuda compiler `nvcc` in windows shell you need to do following

1. install proper toolset version from individual component for VS 2017 - `VC++ 2017 version 15.4 v.14.11 toolset`
2. Run in windows shell following `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 -vcvars_ver=14.11`
3. You can compile `nvcc` code without errors from windows shell

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue using CUDA 9.1 and VS2017 Enterprise.

After changing the VC++ compiler to v140 (instead of 141) everything runs fine.

Already had flags

```
#if _MSC_VER < 1600 || _MSC_VER > 1911
```

But it wouldn't stop showing the error.

No idea why, but trying to run it on VS2015 lead to errors about v141 not being installed... so because of some twisted logic I tried to not use v141 where it was installed... and everything worked!!

Leaving this here as it may help someone else in the same situation. (although I really don't understand the why, how, when, who or what of the solution.

Comment: Adding more details for the needy:
On Visual Studio 2017, compilation of CUDA sample fails because CUDA checks for _MSC_VER in
a specific range, whereas VS2017 latest toolset is too new.

- Right click your project (not your solution) in the Solution Explorer.

- Select "Properties" menu item.

- In the left pane, select "Configuration Properties >> General".

- Change the "Platform Toolset" from "Visual Studio 2017 (v141)" to "Visual Studio 2013 (v120)".

Answer (score 0):

Latest update (correct as of 06/12/2018) latest Cuda version is 9.2 and latest Visual Studio version is 2017.7 do NOT work together. The instructions provided in solution above don't work. Here is what worked for me:

1. Uninstall Visual Studio.
2. Uninstall Visual Studio Installer
3. Download Visual Studio 2017.6 (note that Microsoft is known to change links and revisions without notice) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017
4. Launch installer
5. Go to Individual Components. Click on Windows 10 SDK 10.0.15063
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bImtK.png)
6. Download cuda Toolkit from the official website: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64&target_version=10&target_type=exelocal
7. You may need to download patch.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to edit my CUDA programs using a text editor (i.e. Sublime) and compile them from the command prompt but I ran into an nvcc compiler error. I installed Visual Studio 2017 with Windows 10 OS but after compiling, it said "only version of VS 2012, 13, 15 and 17 are allowed." So what I did was to intall VC++ 2015 toolkit from the installation package of the VS 2017 installer (refer to the image of the top post). I didnt go through his entire process instead, I only copied the path of my cl.exe file from the newly created VS 14.0 folder to the environment variable. The .exe can be found here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just as update. My compatibility is:

- Cuda version 11.2
- Visual Studio Community 2019