# How to configure nvidia CUDA for VIsual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, visual-studio-2017, nvidia

I have nVidia **CUDA 8.0.44** SDK and I recently downloaded Visual Studio 2017,Previously CUDA successfully work with Visual Studio 2015,but this time it's popping out some incompatibility errors while it's being installed.Therefore I want to know ***how to build Visual C++ template project structure in VS 2017 for CUDA 8*** ?

(Please need clear solution, If some one knows news or rumour about CUDA 9 or CUDA 8 support for **VS2017** please do not hesitate to mention it.)
Thank you.

Comment: CUDA 8 is not compatible with VS 2017

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thnx for the quick reply.That means I have to wait until CUDA 9 release?

Comment: Or you could use VS2015

Comment: VS2015 is now behind a paywall.

Comment: VS2015 can be gotten for free.  A description is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43745099/using-cuda-with-visual-studio-2017/44203285#44203285).  Also CUDA 9 RC was made available yesterday at developer.nvidia.com, and it has support for VS2017.

Comment: @RobertCrovella thank you for the info.