# CUDA: Triple Angle Brackets gives me an error in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda

I'm getting an error that says "expected an expression" after the third opening angular bracket. After doing some research online, I know that my problem lies within Visual Studio and the compiler. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

main.cu file

`add<<<1,1>>>(d_a, d_b, d_c);`

Edit: it seems to me that I properly configured the include and lib directories.

Comment: Did you install cuda for VS? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43745099/using-cuda-with-visual-studio-2017

Comment: I can't run the VS installer. I'm using a school computer and I'm blocked by the admin.

Comment: Tough, then VS won't be able to understand your .cu file, it requires a dedicated parser that is only available with CUDA.