# Installing CUDA for Tensorflow on Windows

Tags: visual-studio, tensorflow, cuda

According to [CUDA installation guids](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html), it needs a version of Microsoft Visual Studio to install and run on Windows. I downloaded the community version of Visual Studio 2017 which contains lots of components to install. Each component needs huge amount of space on disk to install, So I don't want to install unnecessary components and waste my hard disk. Which components are necessary to install and run CUDA?

[image]

Comment: Just C++, but unsure exactly which ones you can skip, if any. However, i don't think they need a "huge disk space" each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44957096/3921660

If you want to use CUDA with VisualStudio 2017 without the tool chain for VisualStudio 2015 you have to use CUDA10 (an newer).